# TWRCharts is not drawing charts

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

I want to use charts in my app, for different purpose and UI TWRCharts are best for my needed.
But when I try to add TWRCharts to my project, charts are not drawing.
Here is the screenshots what I've actually wrote to do so.
[image: header file]
[image: main file]

If you see from [library](https://github.com/chasseurmic/TWRCharts) it self, I've written same code they have given.
I crossed check that wether `viewChart`'s IBOutlet is connected or not.
I'm also able to change background color of `self.chartView`.I've integrated this library via cocoapods.
 Can you please help me to find where I've done something wrong?

Comment: it is not about current lib that you try to use but i suggest to you Chart -> https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts. Because it s so clear and you can find a lot of example on web.

Comment: @GökhanAydın ,  But the library that you suggested is displaying fractional digits when I have values for Y axis between 0 to 3. Can I set only int values on Y axis for display?

Comment: yeah you can do it with this lib so easily

Comment: @GökhanAydın ,  I didn't get setting for this. have you any?

Comment: You can get example from github address that i wrote in my first commend. There are swift and objective c example exists and a lot of chart type usage also exists into the project